# How to mount FreeBSD 9.0 iso file writable mode?

Tags: freebsd, mount, iso, readonly

I want to edit bsdinstall script of freebsd 9.0 iso file.

I tried to extract files,edit and recreate iso but I couldn't boot it.I realized that some of files missed while extracting. I also use tools like "ISO Master" but when I try to open it, I get this error:

> Failed to read directory tree: 'Rockridge filename missing when
>   expected on image'

Now I am trying to mount it and edit inside mounted directory. But I can mount it only read-only format. 
Is there any way to mount writable format so that I can edit it?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26237/iso-file-readonly

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit file on mounted ISO image. But you can create a new one with all needed files. [/usr/src/tools/tools/cd2dvd/cd2dvd.sh](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/tools/tools/cd2dvd/cd2dvd.sh?view=markup) script uses `mkisofs` from `sysutils/cdrtools` (it's invoked in the end of the script). As you can see, it uses `/boot/cdboot` as boot image.